# how to linked list pointer sorting

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

[50]->[20]->[10]->[30]
Please tell me how to order misaligned lists in ascending or descending order by the node pointed by the node. 
I think this is called Link sort

p.s Since I am a beginner in C language and English, I need consideration.
    ptr==tail(ptr not head)

```
void sort_data(Node* ptr){
    Node* head = ptr->Next;
    Node* tail = ptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (head->Next == tail) {
        }
        if (head->data < head->Next->data) {
            Node* swap1 = head;
            Node* swap2 = head->Next;
            swap1->Next = swap2->Next;
            swap2->Next = swap1;
            tail->Next = swap2;
            tail = tail->Next;
        }
        else {
            head = head->Next;
            tail = tail->Next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list is a circular list, so a tail pointer is good enough, since as shown in the code, tail->next will result in the head pointer. The code is not checking for an empty list or a list with just a single node.

A bubble sort normally needs a loop within a loop (an outer loop and an inner loop). Each inner loop moves the node that should be last to the end of the list. The first inner loop puts the last node into place, the second inner loop puts the next to last node into place, and so on, where the last inner loop puts the second node into place.

In order to swap nodes, the code needs to be able to update the previous nodes next pointer. For example:

```
A->B->C->D     // to swap B and C, A's next pointer needs to be updated
A->C->B->D     //  along with B and C's next pointers
```

Since the pointer returned is the tail pointer, the tail pointer can either be set after the first inner loop, since that is when the last node is put into place, or after sorting, the list could be scanned to find the last node.

I would suggest converting the circular list to a normal list within the sort function:

```
    Node *head = ptr->next;   // same as above
    Node *tail = ptr;         // same as above
    tail->next = NULL;        // convert to normal list
```

This simplifies determining the end of a list (check for NULL versus a pointer to a specific node) since the nodes at the beginning or end of a list may get swapped during the sort.

The code could be optimized by keeping track of the sorted nodes at the end of the list to avoid scanning and comparing already sorted nodes.

Example code of optimized bubble sort. After setting pHead, the list is changed from circular to normal (pTail->next = NULL). pEnd is used to keep track of the end of the unsorted list and is initialized to NULL. pnEnd is keeps track of the end of the unsorted list based on the out of order check and is used to set pEnd for the next inner loop. The sort is done when pEnd is the second node in the list, since the first node as a single node would also be sorted. ppCurr is a pointer to pointer to the current node, and is a pointer to either pHead or some nodes next pointer, which simplifies the logic for handling the first and then later nodes (in other languages that don't support pointers, a dummy node can be used in a similar way, using dummy.next similar to *ppCurr). A check for the first time the inner loop completes is done to set pTail to the last node, which may have changed if the last two nodes were swapped. When the sort is done, pTail->next is set to pHead to change the list back to circular.

```
/* bubble sort circular linked list */
NODE * SortList(NODE *pTail)
{
NODE *pHead;                    /* ptr to first node */
NODE *pEnd;                     /* ptr to end of unsorted part of list */
NODE *pnEnd;                    /* pEnd for next pass */
NODE *pNext;                    /* ptr to next node */
NODE **ppCurr;                  /* ptr to ptr to curr node */
    if(pTail == NULL || pTail->next == pTail) /* if empty list or single node */
        return pTail;           /*  return pTail */
    pHead = pTail->next;
    pEnd = pTail->next = NULL;  /* change to normal list */
    do{
        ppCurr = &pHead;        /* set ppCurr to start of list */
        pnEnd = pHead->next;    /* set pnEnd to 2nd node */
        while((pNext = (*ppCurr)->next) != pEnd){
            if((*ppCurr)->data > pNext->data){ /* if out of order swap */
                (*ppCurr)->next = pNext->next;
                pnEnd = pNext->next = *ppCurr;
                *ppCurr = pNext;
            }
            ppCurr = &(*ppCurr)->next; /* advance to next node */
        }
        if(pEnd == NULL)        /* if first time, set pTail */
            pTail = *ppCurr;    /*  in case last two nodes swapped */
        pEnd = pnEnd;           /* update pEnd since rest of list is sorted */
    }while(pEnd != pHead->next); /* loop until pEnd => 2nd node */
    pTail->next = pHead;        /* change to circular list */
    return pTail;
}
```

Comment: First, thank you for your answer.I used to use two loops to sort of bubble, but I couldn't solve the endless loop of loops, but could you give me a simple bubble arrangement

Comment: @Lucir - a simple way to end the loop is to use a swap flag. In the outer loop set swap flag to 0, and in the inner loop, if nodes are out of order and swapped, set swap flag to 1. Then in the outer loop, break if swap == 0 (meaning all nodes are in order), otherwise, if the swap flag was set to 1, do another loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a lot of help.Have a nice day.

Comment: @Lucir - I updated my answer to show example code for an optimized bubble sort. A [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) would be much faster. It would be faster still to convert the list to an array or create an array of pointers to nodes, sort the array, and create a new list from the sorted array.